# Keystone.js error in terminal 'Error: Cannot find module 'keystone'

Tags: node.js, terminal, node-modules, keystonejs

```
Error: Cannot find module 'keystone'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/splum/my-test-project/wiki/keystone.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
```

I have ran npm install, deleted modules and tried to reinstall but still getting this error when trying to run the command 'node keystone'. Not sure why! Does anyone know why this won't run?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to kill and re-run mongodb, then all worked swimmingly, I was being a noob.